# Surfaceview - moving around bitmap at the same speed with different fps

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have many bitmaps I move around on a surfaceview and sometimes the fps drops which makes the bitmap move slow or super fast randomly, I've seen someone post a solution using system time or something like that, but couldn't find it, so I wonder if anyone knows how can I make the speed be the same even if the fps drops.

Edit:

I thought that maybe I can calculate time different using:

```
int myFPS;
        if(gameLoopThread.startTime!=System.currentTimeMillis())
     myFPS=(int) (1000 / (gameLoopThread.startTime-System.currentTimeMillis())*-1);
        else
            myFPS=25;
        float new2=1;
     new2=25/myFPS;
```

and then just multiple

```
currentSpeed.y += speed*new2;
```

but it didn't work out because the fps showed was wrong, but I think this is the way to do it? or I might be wrong..

Comment: The correct ways to do a game loop: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

**Single threaded loop**:

To keep the speed of your game at a constant rate, you will have to skip rendering at some point, should a loop iteration take longer than expected.

```
while(isRunning){

            beginTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); 
            framesSkipped = 0;

            //Update game state
            update();

            render();

            //how long we took to update and render
            loopTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - beginTime;
            //calculate how long to sleep
            sleepTime = loopPeriod - timeDiff; 

                //All work was done on time.
                if (sleepTime > 0) { 
                    try { 
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime); 
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
                } 

                //We were too slow. Update without rendering.
                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) { 
                  update();
                    //make sure we don't keep looping here.
                    sleepTime += loopPeriod; 
                    framesSkipped++; 
                }
            }
        }
```

This loop prioritizes your logic updates, and skips rendering if we are behind. The benefit is, that your game-actors are updated constantly and independently from possible frame rate drops.

**Two threads:** (original answer)

Another way to ensure steady movement at low FPS, is to do rendering in one thread, and logical stuff in another one.

Example for the game logic thread:

```
while(isRunning){

        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        //update game logic, no rendering.
        update();

        //time it took to update the game state.
        loopTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        //pausing here to make sure we update the right amount per second.
        if(loopTime < updatePeriod){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(updatePeriod-updateTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Interrupted while sleeping");
            }
        }
    }
```

The update period is the amount of milliseconds a single update iteration is allowed to take.

```
updatePeriod = 1000 / ups;
```

ups = updates per second. If your game runs at 60 fps max, use 60 ups.

Note that both loops are very basic, and, without modification, not suitable for advanced applications.

Also, use SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); it's more reliable.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach unless your update rate is attempting to match the display rate, in which case you're going to get beating effects in the animation as the clocks go in and out of phase. For the separate-threads approach, you really want the state update thread to move things when they naturally move -- e.g. if enemies move twice per second, it should only wake up 2x per second if the player isn't moving. Not all games fit this model well.

Comment: FWIW, use of `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()` is recommended over `System.currentTimeMillis()` because they use the monotonic clock, not because they offer increased precision. The key difference is that the "wall clock" time returned by `currentTimeMillis()` can go backward or jump forward if the network updates the clock, while the others just increment at a steady rate.

Comment: That's actually what I meant with "precision". I'll rephrase that.

Comment: Thanks both, it helps with the problems of when the game speeds up, but as I said before most of the time the game gets slow downs so when the FPS drops I want to speed up the player speed so it wont look like the player moves at not constant speed, do you know how to do that?

Comment: @SpoocyCrep: I added a link to the Graphics Architecture doc section that talks about game loops in a comment below your question. You can see a trivial example in Grafika's "record GL app" activity, which drops frames regularly and (to my eye) invisibly, especially on Qualcomm-based devices (which actively throttle clocks down when not interactive). It's also interesting to play with the "scheduled swap" activity, comparing the apparent smoothness of 50fps vs. 30fps -- 30fps looks smoother despite doing fewer updates per second.  https://github.com/google/grafika

Comment: @SpoocyCrep: For single thread-loops: You could check how long the rendering process takes, and if it took longer than it should, you skip the rendering process in the next iteration and sleep for the remaining time. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @fadden I've seen the doc and both it and the github from what I understood are if the fps is higher, using sleep is in case the fps is higher than the fps I set before, but I still don't see how can it help if the fps drops. What I ask for is just calculation of using the starttime and end time to change the speed, not using sleep or sdk, I know its possible because I seen it somewhere before... but I can't find it.

Comment: @HarrySilver that will only help if the fps is higher.. sleeping wont make it faster, only slower.

Comment: @SpoocyCrep I'm sorry, the trick is not the sleeping, but the skipping of the rendering process. Have a look here for a visual representation. http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/

Comment: @HarrySilver I might be stupid, but I still can't see how when the fps is lower than the normal fps it will make the speed be faster, skipping is again what will help if the fps is higher.. but I dont see how the solution works with low fps..

Comment: @SpoocyCrep By skipping the rendering process, we buy the time we need to ensure the updating rate remains constant. The result is that the game will always run at the same speed, even if the FPS are low. I'll update my answer if you want.

Comment: @HarrySilver okay, please show I'm a bit confused edit: oh you already did, okay ill try it

Comment: @SpoocyCrep: the idea is to move from a system where you have a fixed frame rate to one where you have a fluid frame rate. Instead of saying, "the enemy moves 10 units each frame at 25 fps", you say "the enemy moves 1 unit every 4ms", and you keep track of the passage of time. If the frame rate is very fast, you move the enemy very little. If things get slow and you're dropping frames, you move the enemy farther on the next update. To keep the pacing even you can use Choreographer to get the display refresh times. An example without Choreographer: https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/

Comment: @fadden thank you, it seem to work, but there is a serious fps problem, I believe it has to do with a memory leak, ill open a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

How I kept track of fps 1000milliseconds / 25 = 40 fps

At the start of the while loop make sure you get the time.

```
long starttime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then after everything is finished and rendered you get the time again.

```
long endtime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Subtract start time from end time then divide by 1000 multiply by -1 to get how many times your runnable can loop in a second.

```
int MyFPS = (int) (1000 / (starttime - endtime) * -1);
```

If your answer is 75 then you're running at 75fps.

You just need to put the thread to sleep for 35 milliseconds to be at 40fps.
Tracking the low fps I never got around to doing.  Hope this helps a little though.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (THREAD) {
        long starttime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (!myHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;
        Update();         <----Running the game.
        Main_Render();    <----Rendering graphics.
        long endtime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int MyFPS = (int) (1000 / (starttime - endtime) * -1);
            if (MyFPS >= 25) {
                sleep_length = MyFPS - 25;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleep_length);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps but the problem in my app is that most of the time there are fps drops. I remember that in the solution I seen a while ago he used the starttime and endtime, and calculated something that he multiplied the speed by, which made the speed always the same no matter what fps it is. I wonder what it was..

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it assumes the game drives the frame rate.  It doesn't.  The display panel will refresh at a given rate, which can vary slightly over time, and the game needs to match it.  If you're trying to run your game at 50fps, and the panel is running at 60fps, you're not going to have smooth animation.